# Stop On Error Goto in Debug mode for a sub

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling

I have a problem with error handling while in Debug mode with Visual Basic 2017 . In my program I have different forms and in the Debug mode I want to cancel the On error Goto for some subs, to see how it will go. But VB is jumping constant to the last On Error Goto label

For example; 
I have;
Form Splash.vb with

```
Private Sub Load_SystemDB()
On error GoTo ErrorHandling
     Call DB_SystemSettings_Load
     Exit Sub
ErrorHandling:
Do something when error
End Sub
```

In module modDataBases I then have

```
Public Sub DB_SystemSettings_Load() 
       Do something
End sub
```

Now when there is an error in the Sub DB_SystemSettings_Load, it jumps to the;

```
Form Splash.vb 
           Sub Load_SystemDB()
               ErrorHandling
```

I did try with On Error GoTo 0 and On Error GoTo -1. But it didn’t help. If I remove the On Error Goto ErrorHandling in the sub Load_SystemDB() then it goes tot he pevious On Error Goto.

How can I stop On Error Goto for a sub so it doesn’t go tot he last set Error handling and it breaks on the error in that particular Sub

Comment: Start not using the old VB6 error handling and use the Try Catch VB.NET way to handle exceptions.

Comment: Hello Steve, thanks for your information. However, I think that Try Catch isn't Always the best solution for all sub routine.As I am also affraid Try Catch will slow down the code.